# multiple authenticode signatures

Tags: windows, digital-signature

Is it possible to have multiple Authenticode signatures in an executable? The Digital Signatures tab suggests you can, so I was wondering if, for example, you can sign an executable with Verisign's signature (for Windows), and also a self signed one in the same executable.

I've searched the Internet and can find vague mentions of dual signing and people supposedly signing an executable with multiple certificates, but nothing concrete.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/as` switch to signtool.exe does that:

> /as - Appends this signature. If no primary signature is present, this
> signature is made the primary signature.

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool

Comment: [See also this TechNet section](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx#How_to_dual_sign_files) for an example on how to use `/as`.